# Parse 100GB File Storage Limit

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud, storage

Hey guys so I developed a social network on iOS and used parse for the back end. Our app has taken off and over 50,000 images have been posted in ten days. Aside from hitting the 600 req/sec api limit soon it appears we might fill up the 100gb storage limit sooner. Does this limit (file storage) reset monthly, or once you hit 100gb you are done. It seems like a tiny amount of storage for a PaaS company.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the name of your app?

Comment: klink - share content, get paid

Comment: How have you solved? What happens when you get to 100GB?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Parse.com website, you receive 2TB *file* storage in with any package, not 100GB. If you're asking if they give you an additional 2TB each month, the answer would be no. At the beginning of the next month, you are still using the space, it does not reset (unlike, for example, bandwidth). This is the case with (probably) all cloud (SaaS, IaaS, PaaS, etc.) providers. You can increase the amount of file storage for 10c/GB per month.

As for database storage, it seems that 100GB is the hard limit. Again, being storage, you do not get an extra 100GB per month.

If your database is larger than 100GB and you are hitting more than 600 req/sec (averaged over a minute - i.e. 36000 req/min) then you may want to consider building your own infrastructure, perhaps in AWS or similar, so you can scale it properly. You may also want to consider moving your uploaded images outside of the database if they are not already - DB storage is considerably more expensive than file storage - both in terms of cost and performance.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KYL2lbp.png
So my concern is that once we hit this 20gb limit of storage they just up us again to another 20gig totaling 40gb until we hit the limit of 2TB? I couldn't find any info on the website.

Comment: It sounds like you are on an old plan. Maybe see if you can upgrade to the new plans or contact their support

Answer (score -1):

Parse.com has larger plans available - up to a point.

HOWEVER - if you are going to be doing 600 requests a second (wow, since that's 50 MILLION requests a day) you'll need to look at two possibilities:

1. You can keep you requests under this limit by using local caching, streamlined calls, etc.
2. You will eventually need to migrate off of the Parse ecosystem.

If memory serves, there used to be an option to get a custom plan with more requests/second. It seems to have disappeared from the Pricing page, to be replaced with this:

> **What is the cost for an app with a burst limit above 600 requests per second? What happens if I require more than 600 requests/second?**
>   We do not provide custom plans for apps that require more than 600 requests per second.

UPDATE: It looks like there is also a hard limit of 100GB of file storage...

> The overage rate for database size is $10/GB but we only allow increases in increments of 20GB. When you you exceed 20GB of database size we will increase your soft limit to 40GB and begin charging you an incremental $200/month. When you hit your soft limit of 40GB we will increase your soft limit to 60GB... and so on up to a hard limit of 100GB.